# TSQL - Query to list A and B's columns, A left join, keeping the main table

Tags: sql-server

I can't explain very well what I'm trying to do, but.

I have a table A that is a series of parameters to my Table B wich contains each User and its permissions.

Woot?

**Table User**

UserId, Name

**Table Parameters** 

ParamterId, ParameterName

**Table Permissions** 

PermissionId, ParameterId, UserId, X, Y, Z (X, Y, Z are all booleans)

SO. What I want is; A list of all parameters, per user, having or not, its permission.

It would be something like;

```
SELECT

p.ParameterName,
pm.X,
pm.Y,
pm.Z

FROM Parameters p
LEFT JOIN Permissions pm ON pm.PermissionId = p.Id
AND (pm.UserId IS NULL OR pm.UserId = @UserId)
```

Basically, I want ALL parameters, and I need to know if the user I'm providing has or not, permission for each specific parameter.

LEFT JOIN didn't work very well for me, it doesn't get me all the parameters when a user doesn't have a permission for it...

BUT.

I managed to do it like this;

```
SELECT

 p.ParameterName,
 (SELECT X FROM Permissions WHERE ParameterId = p.Id And UserId = @UserId) [X]
-- *repeat logic for Y and Z*

FROM Parameters p
```

The second query works just fine, but, I know it's not very good on quality and performance. I don't know if my table structure is the best I could do.

I thought about doing it per row instead of doing all the permission types in one line.

Something like.

**Actual - Permissions** 
PermissionId, ParameterId, UserId, X, Y, Z. (XYZ bit/boolean)

**Something I first thought - Permissions**
PermissionId, ParameterId, UserId, Type 
 (Type would have been a enum containing X,Y and Z). But using this logic I'd have more problems querying all of the permissions together, so, I thought that if I put them in one single row could be better.

Did I managed to explain my problem and what I need?

Is there something else I can do or the second query works just fine?

Thanks.

Comment: at first look LEFT JOIN wrong it should be LEFT JOIN Permissions pm ON pm.ParameterId= p.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.ParameterName,
    pm.X,
    pm.Y,
    pm.Z
FROM Parameters p
LEFT JOIN Permissions pm ON pm.ParameterId = p.Id
AND (pm.UserId IS NULL OR pm.UserId = @UserId)
```

Comment: Frick. I'm embarassed. I did the where clause all wrong, at least my it was right in heart, lol. Thanks. I would accept this as correct as soon as possible.